# Python OpenCV return list of objects in an image

Tags: python, opencv

Python OpenCV return list of objects in an image

I'm trying to detect the animals found inside an image, then return a list of their names.

For example the image `object.png` has a lion, giraffe and a zebra.

I would like the program to return a list 'lion','giraffe','zebra' as the animals found in the image.

The current code returns an empty list.

Could you please help me spot where the problem is?

What is the appropriate classifier to use to detect the animals using openCV?

Thanks in advance!

```py
import cv2

src_img = cv2.imread('object.png')
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(src_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
c_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier(f"{cv2.data.haarcascades}haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml")
d_objects = c_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray_img, minSize=(50, 50))

print(d_objects)
```

Comment: if you want to detect several object classes, you probably need a cnn, like yolo, not cascades

Answer (score 2):

I believe that "haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml" is used to detect cats, not animals generally. For more information refer [here](https://pyimagesearch.com/2016/06/20/detecting-cats-in-images-with-opencv/).

Also haarcascade classifiers are used to find bounding boxes. After the object (animal) is found from the image you should crop the image use different classifier to detect which animal is in the sub-image. Or use different classifier in the first place which I would do if you only need the information which animals are in the image.